# Alter Django Form Fields based on User Selection

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have three models: `Product`, `Product Class` and `Product Attributes`. Now when the user is shown a page to create a new product, he/she needs to select the `Product Class` from a dropdown. Based on this selection, `Product Attributes` will have to refresh dynamically (using AJAX) and allow the user to enter specific information.

For example: A product type could be `Automobiles`, in which case the user should be required to enter `Tyre Size`, `Fuel Tank Capacity`, etc. or a product type could be `Electronics` and the user will be required to enter `RAM`, `Storage Capacity`, etc.

The question is how do I manage this in Django. My view has a product form but I cannot add attribute fields to this form as I don't know what `product class` the user will select. So basically, I need to alter form fields (add attribute fields) based on user selection. How do I do that?

Currently, once the product is saved and then opened again for editing, I am adding the appropriate attribute fields using the code:

```
def add_attribute_fields(self):
    """
    For each attribute specified by the product class, this method
    dynamically adds form fields to the product form.
    """
    for attribute in self.instance.product_class.attributes.all():
        field = self.get_attribute_field(attribute)
        if field:
            self.fields['attr_%s' % attribute.code] = field
```

But this largely relies on the product instance already created. I want the user to be able to enter data when creating a new product as well. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects the `ProductClass`, you could sent (AJAX) the `pk` to Django and based on that, have Django return the appropriate input form fields HTML, using the regular `django.forms` to render it.

Then insert that HTML into your original form, so it shows to the user.

That way, when the user submits the form, you have "two forms in one" that you can process with Django forms as usual. Create the `ProductClass` first, and then the dependent `ProductAttributes`.

If the user changes their opinion while filling the form, you can remove the dynamically inserted form fields, and send another AJAX request to Django to get the form fields for the new selected `ProductClass`.